# I am converting following oracle query to bigquery but the result record counts are different

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

I am converting following oracle query to bigquery query but the results(record counts) are different, eventhough base tables involved in the query are having same number of records in both oracle and bq.

### oracle :

```
SELECT
to_char(R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_COPYRIGHT_YEAR),
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_TITLE,
to_char(R_PROJECT_S.EDITION),
R_PROJECT_S.CIRCULATION_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.DISTRIBUTION_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID,
UPPER(DB.R_INFO_S.PHOTOGRAPHER),
UPPER(DB.R_INFO_S.SOURCE_CAPTION),
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEAU,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHECPYR,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEED,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEPRDDE,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEGRDE,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHSODE,
R_PROJECT_S.CHARGE_TO_ISBN,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEPTIT,
DB.R_INFO_S.SOURCE_NAME,
R_PROJECT_S.LANGUAGE_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_FORMAT_DESC,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_ID,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.PAGE,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.CHAPTER,
DB.R_INFO_S.WORK_PROJECT_ID,
DB.R_INFO_S.IMAGE_TYPE_DESC,
DB.R_INFO_S.IMAGE_DESC,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_TYPE_DESC,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_STATUS_DESC,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_USAGE_DESC,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_LABEL,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.QUOTED_COST,
DB.R_INFO_S.SOURCE_OBJECT_ID,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_TYPE_DESC,
GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP.TITLE_DESCRIPTION,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHESOAB,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHEGRCD
FROM
DB.R_PROJECT_S_VW  R_PROJECT_S,
DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S,
DB.R_INFO_S,
ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW,
DB.GHEPM_TITLE  GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP
WHERE
( R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.PROJECT_ID(+)
)
AND  ( DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID=DB.R_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID  )
AND  ( R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=ADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW.BIC_ZCHETIIS(+)  )
AND  ( R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=DB.GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP.ISBN10(+)  ) 
AND  UPPER(DB.R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_LABEL)  NOT LIKE  UNISTR('%KILL%')
```

### BQ:

```
SELECT
CAST(R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_COPYRIGHT_YEAR AS string) COPYRIGHT_YEAR,
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_TITLE,
CAST(R_PROJECT_S.EDITION AS string) EDITION,
R_PROJECT_S.CIRCULATION_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.DISTRIBUTION_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID,
UPPER(R_INFO_S.PHOTOGRAPHER) PHOTOGRAPHER,
UPPER(R_INFO_S.SOURCE_CAPTION) SOURCE_CAPTION,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEAU,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHECPYR,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEED,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEPRDDE,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEGRDE,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHSODE,
R_PROJECT_S.CHARGE_TO_ISBN,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEPTIT,
R_INFO_S.SOURCE_NAME,
R_PROJECT_S.LANGUAGE_DESC,
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_FORMAT_DESC,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_ID,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.PAGE,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.CHAPTER,
R_INFO_S.WORK_PROJECT_ID,
R_INFO_S.IMAGE_TYPE_DESC,
R_INFO_S.IMAGE_DESC,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_TYPE_DESC,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_STATUS_DESC,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.PERMISSION_USAGE_DESC,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_LABEL,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.QUOTED_COST,
R_INFO_S.SOURCE_OBJECT_ID,
R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_TYPE_DESC,
GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP.TITLE_DESCRIPTION,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHESOAB,
BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHEGRCD  
FROM
`domain-rr.oracle_DB_DB.R_info_s` R_INFO_S
inner join 
`domain-rr.oracle_DB_DB.R_usage_info_s` R_USAGE_INFO_S
on 
R_USAGE_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID=R_INFO_S.OBJECT_ID
right outer join
`domain-rr.DB_RPT.R_PROJECT_S_VW` R_PROJECT_S
on 
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=R_USAGE_INFO_S.PROJECT_ID
left outer join
`domain-rr.DB_RPT.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW` BIC_APHEISBN00_BO
ON
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=BIC_APHEISBN00_BO._BIC_ZCHETIIS
left outer join
`domain-rr.oracle_DB_DB.ghepm_title` GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP
ON
R_PROJECT_S.PROJECT_ID=GHEPM_TITLE_PSPP.ISBN10
AND UPPER(R_USAGE_INFO_S.USAGE_LABEL)  NOT LIKE '%KILL%'
```

Oracle count - 1553437
BQ count -  2414413

Please help me on how to get counts are same on both oracle and bq

Thanks,
Naren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you used more readable, shortened table aliases several differences can be illuminated:

- Oracle does not attempt any `RIGHT JOIN`;
- GBQ should run `UPPER(...)` expression in `WHERE` not on last `LEFT JOIN` clause or move expression to `INNER JOIN` on *ui* table (but without testing may not make a difference but readability);
- Table order may make a difference especially with use of both `INNER` and `OUTER` joins;

Oracle *(using the older, outdated implicit joins)*

```
...
FROM
      GRDW.RMS_IMAGE_PROJECT_S_VW p,
      GRDW.RMS_IMAGE_USAGE_INFO_S ui,
      GRDW.RMS_IMAGE_INFO_S i,
      BOADMIN.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW b,
      GRDW.GHEPM_TITLE g
WHERE
  ( p.PROJECT_ID = ui.PROJECT_ID(+)                      -- LEFT JOIN
  )
  AND  ( ui.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID  )                   -- INNER JOIN
  AND  ( p.PROJECT_ID = b.BIC_ZCHETIIS(+) )              -- LEFT JOIN
  AND  ( p.PROJECT_ID = g.ISBN10(+)  )                   -- LEFT JOIN
  AND  UPPER(ui.USAGE_LABEL)  NOT LIKE  UNISTR('%KILL%')
```

Google BigQuery *(using current standard of explicit joins)*

```
...
FROM
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.rms_image_info_s` i
INNER JOIN 
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.rms_image_usage_info_s` ui 
   ON ui.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
      `pearson-rr.GRDW_RPT.RMS_IMAGE_PROJECT_S_VW` p 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = ui.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `pearson-rr.GRDW_RPT.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW` b 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = b._BIC_ZCHETIIS
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.ghepm_title` g 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = g.ISBN10
   AND UPPER(ui.USAGE_LABEL) NOT LIKE '%KILL%'
```

---

Therefore, to account for table order and appropriate `JOIN`, consider below adjusted Google BigQuery:

```
...
FROM
     `pearson-rr.GRDW_RPT.RMS_IMAGE_PROJECT_S_VW` p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.rms_image_usage_info_s` ui 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = ui.PROJECT_ID
INNER OUTER JOIN 
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.rms_image_info_s` i
   ON ui.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND UPPER(ui.USAGE_LABEL) NOT LIKE '%KILL%'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `pearson-rr.GRDW_RPT.BIC_APHEISBN00_BO_VW` b 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = b._BIC_ZCHETIIS
LEFT OUTER JOIN
      `pearson-rr.oracle_grdw_grdw.ghepm_title` g 
   ON p.PROJECT_ID = g.ISBN10
```